# Workaround for logging objects to console in Chrome

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

If you execute this code:

```
var foo = {bar: 'baz'};
window.console.log(foo);
foo.bar = 'bla';
```

The console shows this after expanding the object:

[image]

(when logging objects and arrays, it's not the run-time value that's recorded)

This bug was documented over a year ago:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50316

Is there a workaround for logging objects in Chrome?

Comment: A simple solution could be to override `console.log` and with a function that clones and logs the input (although it would probably be a shallow copy).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just use `JSON.stringify` when i need it. Don't know if it will do it for you, but it is easy and effective for debugging purposes.

This is no good for objects with function references in it tho, so if you need that i would consider using either a deep copy of the object (you can use jQuery's excellent `extend` method) or roll you own logging function that will loop recursively over the object and print it out.

Comment: I've also used `JSON.stringify(stuff, true, 2)` which will "pretty print" your output. Useful when your JSON is large or unruly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dedicated logging library such as my own [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/).