# Backbone.js model

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

Am I doing something completely wrong here? I am populating a backbone model from a jsonp response. When I view the first console statement in firebug, the 'current' object has 'icon' under attributes. However, when printing `console.log(current.has("icon"))` it returns false and therefore current.get("icon") will return undefined.

```
var Current = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "A_valid_url",
    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        options.timeout = 10000;
        options.dataType = "jsonp";

        return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
    },
    parse: function(response, xhr) {
        return response.current_observation;
        }
});

var current = new Current({test: "blah"});
    current.fetch();
    console.log(current);//under attributes there is a "icon"
    console.log(current.has("icon")); //false
    console.log(current.get("icon")); //undefined
    console.log(current.has("test")); //true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch()` is asynchronous.  Try the following:

```
var current = new Current({test: "blah"});
current.fetch({
    success: function(){
        console.log(current.get("icon"));
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
current.fetch();
console.log(current);//under attributes there is a "icon"
console.log(current.has("icon")); //false
console.log(current.get("icon")); //undefined
console.log(current.has("test")); //true
```

Is that the real code? If so, all this logging will take place *before* the asynchronous loading of the data has completed. You need to do this in a callback (or bind to the "change" event on the model).

```
console.log(current);//under attributes there is a "icon"
```

That the data still shows up in the console log is a "[feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521916/workaround-for-logging-objects-to-console-in-chrome)" of the log when you log objects (instead of strings): It will only pass a reference, and the actual printing happens later (when the data might already be loaded).